# Is it fair to say that "hadoop is a hyper-converged Infrastructure application"?

Tags: hadoop, virtualization, hypervisor, hardware-infrastructure

We hear a lot of buzzwords these says about big data and new data center infrastructure. I am just confused, is it fair to say that "hadoop is a hyper-converged Infrastructure application"?

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop is a bunch of components - 
1. HDFS - a distributed FS running across multiple nodes across a Data center.
2. HBase - A non SQL database running on top of HDFS
3. Zookeeper - A consensus manager

So yes, it is hadoop is a hyper-converged Infrastructure application"
What does that mean ? No idea :P